# Creating new rows in another table for foreign keys

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a structure similar to

```
CREATE TABLE b (b_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
                data INTEGER NULL);

CREATE TABLE a (a_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
                b_id INTEGER NULL REFERENCES b(b_id),
                attrib INTEGER);                 
                
INSERT INTO b (data) values(2);
INSERT INTO b (data) values(3);
INSERT INTO b (data) values(4);
INSERT INTO b (data) values(5);

INSERT INTO a VALUES(1, 1, 13);
INSERT INTO a VALUES(2, 2, 12);
INSERT INTO a VALUES(3, 3, 13);
INSERT INTO a VALUES(4, NULL, 14);
INSERT INTO a VALUES(5, NULL, 15);
INSERT INTO a VALUES(6, NULL, 16);
```

where I'd want to create new distinct rows and in `b` and link those so every row in `a` links to `a`. Several rows in `a` *can* link to the same row in `b` but each row with a `NULL` `b_id` should result in and link to a new row in `b`.

There's no link between the tables except `b_id`. `b_id` can be assumed to be any automatic type (the only additional requirement is that it should be suitable as a primary key).

It's nice if it can be done in a single statement, but that's not a requirement.

I can easily create new rows in `b` corresponding to the rows with missing `b_id` in `a`:

```
INSERT INTO b (data) 
SELECT NULL 
FROM a WHERE a.b_id IS NULL;
```

but have so far not managed to construct an update that does what I want (I tend to end up with all entries in `a` linking to the same newly created row, as e.g.

```
UPDATE a set b_id = bx.b_id 
FROM b bx 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                  FROM a ax 
                  WHERE ax.b_id = bx.b_id) 
  AND a.b_id IS NULL;
```

I've done versions without subselect as well, but with the same result.

There are many possible result after a correct solution (for this example), one would be

| a_id | b_id | attrib |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 13 |
| 2 | 2 | 12 |
| 3 | 3 | 13 |
| 4 | 4 | 14 |
| 5 | 5 | 15 |
| 6 | 6 | 16 |

but equally valid would  be

| a_id | b_id | attrib |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 13 |
| 2 | 2 | 12 |
| 3 | 3 | 13 |
| 4 | 6 | 14 |
| 5 | 4 | 15 |
| 6 | 5 | 16 |

or

| a_id | b_id | attrib |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 13 |
| 2 | 2 | 12 |
| 3 | 3 | 13 |
| 4 | 100 | 14 |
| 5 | 200 | 15 |
| 6 | 300 | 16 |

A test I believe should work for this example is that

```
WITH c AS (
  SELECT b_id, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY b_id) 
  FROM a
) 
SELECT MAX(count) FROM c;
```

should return `1` and

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM a WHERE b_id is NULL;
```

should return `0`.

The primary environment for this is Postgres, but I'd like to keep this as portable as possible. I'd also like to avoid using `WHILE` if possible.

Playground set up: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/2262c/1

Comment: You are not specifying the values of `b_id` when inserting. Your query may run by sheer luck. Remove the `SERIAL` and specify the values explicitly to ensure a repeatable code.

Comment: Please provide the expected result after a few new rows are inserted.

Comment: Added clarifications.

Comment: "*keep this as portable as possible*" - you might want to consider using (standard)  `identity` columns rather than `serial`. The UPDATE syntax using a `FROM` is Postgres specific and not portable.